# How to stop sound when clicking the OFF button

Tags: android, eclipse

```
package net.androidbootcamp.guessinggame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class setting extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.settings);

Button s =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnons);
s.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View v) {


MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(setting.this,R.raw.meow);
mp.start();





                }

    });

Button ss =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnoffs);
ss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
```

How can I code the Off Button.This is my code of ON button.I don't know how to stop the sound when I click the other button(off).

```
 I have two buttons, the ON and OFF button,a normal game settings of sound.
```

I don't know what's next. I want to stop the stop everytime I click the OFF button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably be sufficient to handle the `MediaPlayer` present in your code:

```
package net.androidbootcamp.guessinggame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class setting extends Activity {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        Button s =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnons);
        s.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startMediaPlayer();
                }
            }
        );

        Button ss =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnoffs);
        ss.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener(){ 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    stopMediaPlayer();
                }
            }
        );
    }

     private void startMediaPlayer() {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(setting.this,R.raw.meow);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    private void stopMediaPlayer() {
        if( mediaPlayer != null ) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Changes towards your code:
`mp` is now a member of the class `setting`, called `mediaPlayer`. Previously, you'd have a hard time trying to work on the `mp` in the scope of the "off button"'s `OnClickListener`, but that's solved now. Also wrapped the code in `stopMediaPlayer()` with a null check to avoid a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: how can I recode my codes that my 2buttons will run..The ON and OFF button?

Comment: new OnClickListener(){ 
stopMediaPlayer(); There's a red jaggled line here..how can I fix this?

Comment: @yam Did you try replacing your `Activity` with the code I gave you? You might need to add imports, and if you have any other methods in it - copy them over. I just did what I could from what you had provided in your post.

Comment: the suggestions says in OnClickListener() is "add unimplemented methods" while the { stopMediaPlayer();  are "add body" "add abstract modifier" and "set method return type to void"..how is it?

Comment: Oh, wow, I'm so blind - sorry about that. Check the fixed code.

Comment: It worked!Thanks! do you have a sample codes of inserting a video also?

Comment: You'd have to create a new question for that, per SE's rules. :-) Don't forget to mark this as the answer to the left of the post!

Comment: oh I'm sorry..okay I'll post it..Thanks again..Hope you can help me more:)

Comment: how can i post it as an answer ninetwozero?

Comment: @yam: You see the ^0v? part of it? That's where you upvote an answer on any question if you deem it relevant. Underneath it, there's a check-mark which you should click on to pick an answer to your question. :)